# is it in Jetpack Compose exist possibility to add background image to Column who fill all Column similar like fill color?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to add background image but if i add only Image(){} inside Box ,is not resizable background image to content and contain more space that i want . I found this but not work for me, https://www.tutorialkart.com/android-jetpack-compose/card-background-image/
because i want Image adjustable to column

```
 Card() {
                    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.flower), contentDescription = null)
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
                        Text("AB CDE", fontWeight = FontWeight.W700)
                        Text("+0 12345678")
                        Text("XYZ city", fontWeight = FontWeight.W300)
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage `matchParentSize` modifier available in `Box` scope and scale the image to fit the container.

```kotlin
    Card {
        Box {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.flower),
                contentDescription = "null",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .matchParentSize(),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
            )
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
                Text("AB CDE", fontWeight = FontWeight.W700)
                Text("+0 12345678")
                Text("XYZ city", fontWeight = FontWeight.W300)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used this and it works too : 1. Create mutable state with value :  var iconBoxHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }    2. Get Height object Modifier.onGloballyPositioned { layoutCoordinates -> iconBoxHeight = layoutCoordinates.size.height } 3. And the last one past this value to heigh  image (with(LocalDensity.current) {  iconBoxHeight.toDp() })

Comment: @AagitoEx, Thank you so much. I wasted 3 hrs to search the fix. Finally this solution worked for me!